# How to post response from server to dialogflow?

Tags: node.js, http, post, postman, dialogflow-es

### I changed the question to be more explicitly:

### The server side is node.js and I try to get data like weather from an external API.

### When I send a question with POSTMAN I receive a response from the server. Ok now, the issue...

I use ngrok tunnel on Dialogflow because I need HTTPS not HTTP, and when I try the Dialogflow interface no get the same response from the server as I do with POSTMAN I didn't receive anything, error 404. 
Can someone help me, please?

## I attack here the code with the route.

```
router.post('/weather/textQuery', async (req, res) => {
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    if (currentTime + 4500 >= new Date().getTime()) {
        //currentTime
        try {


            const projectId = process.env.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID_WEATHER
            const sessionId = process.env.DIALOGFLOW_SESSION_ID_WEATHER
            const languageCode = process.env.DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE


            // Create a new session
            const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient();
            const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);
            const request = {
                session: sessionPath,
                queryInput: {
                    text: {
                        // The query to send to the dialogflow agent
                        text: req.body.text,
                        // The language used by the client (en-US)
                        languageCode: languageCode,
                    },
                },
            };

            console.log(request)
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

            const responses = sessionClient.detectIntent(request)
                .then(responses => {
                    const result = responses[0].queryResult;

                    if (result.action === 'input.weather') {
                        console.log("am intrat in if")

                        let city = result.parameters.fields['geo-city'].stringValue; // city is a required param
                        console.log("city" + city)
                        let date = '';
                        if (result.parameters.fields['date'].stringValue) {
                            date = (result.parameters.fields['date'].stringValue);
                            console.log('Date: ' + date);
                        }
                        //result.fulfillmentMessages[0].text[0].text= output
                        callWeatherApi(city, date).then((output) => {
                            var trimite = output

                            console.log("output ul de la API: " + output)
                            //response.json({ 'fulfillmentText': trimite });
                            let response = output;
                            let responseObj = {
                                "fulfillmentText": response
                                , "fulfillmentMessages": [{ "text": { "text": [trimite] } }]
                                , "source": ""
                            }
                            //res.send(JSON.stringify({speech:trimite, displayText: trimite, source:'api-weather'}));
                            return res.json(responseObj);

                        })

                            .catch(() => {
                                res.json({ 'fulfillmentText': `I don't know the weather but I hope it's good!` });
                            });

                    } else {
                        res.send(result);
                        console.log(`  Query: ${result.queryText}`);
                        console.log(`  Response: ${result.fulfillmentText}`);
                    }
                    //res.json({  'fulfillmentText': trimite });


                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.error('ERROR:', err);
                });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Input is " + err);
        }
    }
console.log("current time response: " + currentTime)
})
```

ON POSTMAN IT'S WORK

```
{

    "text" : "weather in Paris tomorrow"
}
```

I received that

```
{
    "fulfillmentText": "Current conditions in the City \n        Paris, France are Sunny with a projected high of\n        22°C or 71°F and a low of \n        14°C or 57°F on \n        2020-05-31.",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
        {
            "text": {
                "text": [
                    "Current conditions in the City \n        Paris, France are Sunny with a projected high of\n        22°C or 71°F and a low of \n        14°C or 57°F on \n        2020-05-31."
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "source": ""
}
```

[Image of fulfillment and were I try to get the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp5l3.png)

Comment: Where doesn't it work?

Comment: i try the dialogflow interface to receive the response from server.

Comment: What response do you get?

Comment: Nothing,  it's like I don't write anything....

Comment: I don't know about their API, but if it works with postman then you can manually make the requests.  use [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to make the requests manually.

Comment: I have attached a picture to understand what I am saying. it's in above of question. "dialogflow interface"

Comment: I don't know how that's the part of the problem there

Comment: I understand, thank you, the client side is a mobile app react-native, i will try to make the request with axios, hope it's works

Comment: Look if that is a **CORS** issue. Postman doesn't have the same problems with retrieving data as a regular web app. LINK: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS